# What is the optimal technique for determining statistical thresholds?

Tags: epidemiology, threshold, nonlinearity

Relevant context: epidemiologists define an outbreak according to six defined stages (investigation, recognition, initiation, acceleration, deceleration, and preparation). From a local perspective, it would be useful to determine what constitutes a change from one phase to another, as they call for different resource allocations.

Question: Statistically speaking, what are the most optimal approaches to determine these thresholds? I can think of at least five ways to find inflection points as shown well here: https://www.wikihow.com/Find-Inflection-Points but in practicality, how about Jenks procedures widely used in ecology?

Comment: You told us the names of the stages, but could you also say what they mean? You consider inflection points of what? Jenks procedure of what data? A link for the Janks procedure would also be helpful to make sure we are not talking about different methods.

Comment: @frank: "Jenks" is presumably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization

Comment: while https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/rr6306a1.htm#Fig gives some suggestion as the CDC meanings of the six stages as they apply to influenza A outbreaks